# RewriteEngine On in <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> every time?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webserver

I'm wondering whether I can use RewriteEngine On only once within my htaccess when it is embed in IfModule mod_rewrite.c or do I have to use it every time *because* it is embeded?

See example below. Thanks

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?author   [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} g=  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should also avoid multiple `RewriteBase` directives. Whilst it won't generate an error, it is invalid to have more than one in any one .htaccess file. The last one wins and controls the entire .htaccess file. In this file it looks unnecessary anyway - AFAIK it's only required when you have relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule` directive.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to put a single check around all your rewrite code.

I suspect from your code that the site you are working on will NOT function properly or at all of mod_rewrite is not enabled. In such cases I would omit the checks for mod_rewrite completely and let the webserver fail if it is not enabled.

If you should ever end up in a situation where your code is installed on a webserver without mod_rewrite enabled it will be a lot easier to debug and pinpoint the exact problem.